# SQL update only if relationship exists

Tags: sql

I have batches and tasks. Upon batching some tasks into another batch I want to close all batches that are now empty by marking deleted = true. I tried to simply select using a join only the batches that have no tasks.:

```
SELECT id FROM batches INNER JOIN tasks on batches.id = tasks.batch_id where count(tasks.id) > 0
```

But this does not seem to work.

Comment: If your ID columns in both tables are named "id" you need to add an alias to the table / column reference as well. Also, is your batch ID the same as your task ID? Because according to the join it looks that way and I'm guessing that isn't a one-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to an outer join. Inner join won't work to get non-matches.

```
SELECT id FROM batches LEFT JOIN tasks on batches.id = tasks.id where tasks.id is null
```

Comment: *Facepalm. I can't believe I didn't think of that.. That's pretty much what outer joins are for, right?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not misunderstanding your problem, this is what you are looking for.

```
UPDATE tbl
SET col=tbl.col
FROM tbl 
INNER JOIN tbl1 ON tbl1.SomeCol=tbl.SomeCol
WHERE ......
```